# exception about weex_sdk:0.18.0

Tags: weex

recently encountered an occasional problem

all of logcat:

```
com.taobao.weex.ui.flat.FlatGUIContext.getFlatComponentAncestor(com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent)' on a null object reference
at com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent.setComponentLayoutParams(WXComponent.java:559)at com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent.setLayout(WXComponent.java:551)
at com.taobao.weex.ui.RenderActionContextImpl.setLayout(RenderActionContextImpl.java:82)
at com.taobao.weex.ui.WXRenderManager.setLayout(WXRenderManager.java:150)
at com.taobao.weex.dom.DOMActionContextImpl$ApplyUpdateConsumer$1.execute(DOMActionContextImpl.java:276)
at com.taobao.weex.ui.WXRenderManager$1.run(WXRenderManager.java:104)
at com.taobao.weex.common.WXThread$SafeRunnable.run(WXThread.java:48)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6114)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
```